# How to convert functions of a class that is not instantiated into delegates?

Tags: c#, .net

I have provided a minimum code below to convey my situation. I just want to figure out a way to create a delegate function for `add(IClient client)` in **`ClientList.cs`** and consume it in **`Program.cs`**

I have provided comments in the code below to better explain my situation. If you need any other information let me know, I'll update it here.

<kbd>**Program.cs**</kbd>

```
namespace sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Go();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        
        private void Go()
        {
        
        //Code logic
            
            using (ClientList clientList = new ClientList())  //Instantiated an object of the ClientList class
            {
                //Code Logic
                
                //Make use of functions from the object instances here.
                clientList.add(client); //Works
                
                //ERROR : BUT, the below does not work . What am i doing wrong here.? Why is it not accessible here ?
                clientList.add
                
                
                
                clientList.Sort();
            }
        
        
            
        //Code logic
        
        
        }
    }

}
```

<kbd>**ClientList.cs**</kbd>

```
namespace sample
{
    
    public delegate void addItems(IClient client);   //ERROR in editor. (Red underline on addItems.)

    class ClientList : IDisposable
    {
        //Member variables
        private List<IClient> clientlist = null;
        private string time;

        //Member Properties
        public string Time { get => time; set => time = value; }

        //Default Constructor
        public ClientList()
        {
            clientlist = new List<IClient>();
        }

        //Member Methods
        public void add(IClient client)
        {
            clientlist.Add(client);
        }

        //Indexer
        public IClient this[int position]
        {
            get { return clientlist[position]; }
        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE #1:

> The red underline error is as follows: CS0059: Inconsistent
> accessibility: parameter type 'IClient' is less accessible than
> delegate 'addItems'

Comment: If you're going to write C#, it would be nice if you could maybe consider being PascalCaseDev ;)

Comment: Red underlines come with a compiler error message. Mention it

Comment: @CaiusJard I'll consider that. I would appreciate if you can help me out here :)

Comment: @CaiusJard Sure, `CS0059: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IClient' is less accessible than delegate 'addItems'`

Comment: You can't make a public variable of a type that is less than public. It doesn't seem related to your question though

Comment: @CaiusJard Can you suggest a fix. I am learning C# actually, would help if you can point me out the mistake

Comment: I'm still trying to work out what you're trying to do, to be honest.. On the line where you say "but the below does not work" - what are you hoping it will achieve? As presented, it's not a statement; it could only be used somewhere that takes a delegate that takes an IClient, but I can't see anywhere that does. Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-delegate-type ?

Comment: @CaiusJard The line where is use `clientList.add(client);` is the regular way of accessing the variable. But the line below that is an attempt to access using concept of delegate.

Comment: I might be being a bit thick, but I genuinely can't understand the aim of this exercise. Simplistically, a delegate is a way of turning a method into an object instance that can be passed around and called(invoked) and the invoking code knows nothing about the method other than its signature. Take `List<T>.ForEach()` method that accepts a delegate representing some code (whatever it is) that list shall call repeatedly, once for each item in the list, passing the list item to the delegate. As a use case it makes sense - you might want to do something to every item in a list but ...

Comment: ..Microsoft cannot know what you want to do so they simply say "pass a delegate of signature X and list will call it over and over again". The delegate declaration exists to ensure the objectified method you pass has a particular signature - think of it like a "Type" for a method. I can't see what you're trying to do with your delegate here; you've declared one that dictates "the method shall accept an IClient" but then you don't use it; you never make a delegate and pass to it a "method that takes an iclient" (and I can't see why you would need to in this code)

Comment: (It would make sense to me if, for example, you provided a method on CLientList called `public void DoForEvery(addItem x) { foreach(var c in clientlist) x.Invoke(c);` - addItem here being poorly named, but meh - and then your outer class Program could define some method like `void PrintIt(IClient x) { Console.Write(x.ToString()); }` and then you could in Main do `clientList.DoForEvery(new addItem(PrintIt))` or even simpler `clientList.DoForEvery(PrintIt)` and every item would be printed. Then another method `void DecrementAge(IClient x){ x.Age--; }` and `clientList.DoForEvery(DecrementAge)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 would be: Remove the public in your delegate definition. This might be a solution.

Otherwise, please provide the definition of the `IClient` interface.